# Customizing Text in Android Edit Text

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am trying to create an EditText which allows users to specifically put in typefaces like bold, italic, underline to specific portions of the text. How should I actually have it coded? How can properly save the changes then? Will it be something like in html with the tags?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Spanned](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html) interface and [android.text.style](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/package-summary.html) package.

This "Common Task" will be helpful too: [Selecting, Highlighting, or Styling Portions of Text](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext).